# Rejected by Google Adsense for weapon related content but my site should be allowed because it is about video game guns, not real ones

Tags: google, google-adsense, advertising, google-adsense-policies

I created a Fortnite website a couple months back called http://fortnitegunstatistics.com. The website contains the statistics for all of the virtual weapons in the video game. My site got rejected about two weeks ago for containing weapons. Obviously, there isn't much I can really do about this, considering my website is about guns.

After looking at the prohibited content page on Adsense, I found that my site is not really violating any of the gun content rules.

Here is what they say:

[image: Google's terms on weapon related content]

So as you can see, my website does not really violate any of these terms. I am not trying to sell these weapons as they are virtual and in a kid friendly video game. They also do not say anything on video game weapons, so if I had read this before I created the website, I would have thought that I was in the clear.

The reason why I made this thread is because I wanted to know if there may be a way for me to reword some text on my site to clarify to Google that my site only contains virtual video game weapons. If any of you have an idea of how I could work around this, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Google AdSense often doesn't use humans to review the content, it just sends a bot out that is looking for keywords.     You would probably need to remove the word "gun" from your site entirely while you are applying or apply with a different website first.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just some ideas to consider:

- You only use the word "video" once.
- You use the word "game" twice.

Switching the focus from guns to game (or "gaming guns") might help to achieve your goal. You could also reformat the site so that the guns are separated into which levels you can access them in, or what/where in the game you have to do to get the gun. That provides a gun grouping based on acheivement and not focused on the type of the weapon. Some combination of those may allow Google's automation to better understand the purpose of the site and not associate it with gun sales.

Comment: Alright man, seems like a good idea